# Advanced query with Elasticsearch (How to do JOIN)

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm currently moving from a RDBMS world into the NO SQL world, and i'm trying to solve an issue.
I'm using ElasticSearch, and i have 2 indexes:
1st index, "routes", contains a person name and GeoLocation array of points, whith routes he made during the last week.
2nd index, "address", contains a list of addresses -> a person name, and a geo location point of his house.

Now, i want to make an advanced query, which will allow the user to filter something like:
- Give me all the people which their house is in a specific polygon(A), and also has route which within another polygon(B)

it's like doing a JOIN statement on the person name - 
how can i make such a thing using ElasticSearch? I'm writing my code in JAVA

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: you can't do a SQL-equivelant JOIN in Elasticsearch, its just not how it works.

The long answer: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relations.html

You should create your collections with certain relationships between them.

Though in your situation, I suggest you just save everything in the same collection and handle it from there, Elasticsearch can handle it.

Comment: What I suggested is changing the structure of your indices. Try here for your options: http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Joining-2-indices-in-Elasticsearch-td4033780.html